# Validate column values in two different data frame and append mismatched values to existing data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

So I have 2 data frames `df1` and `df2`, with two columns `Curr_Time` and `Curr_Date` in both the data frames. I should compare the values of `Curr_Time` in both the data frames, if the values are same then do nothing else if the values are different then append the new values the `df1`.

I am dealing with streaming data where `df2` has only one row with the latest value. My aim is to append the new values in the `df2` to `df1` if and only if the values in `df2$Curr_Time != df1$Curr_Time`. Currently, I am able to append all the values to the `df1` irrespective of the above-mentioned logic.

`df2`: This has the only one row gets updated for every `5 seconds`

```
     Curr_Time        Curr_Date
     11:45:34         10-04-2018
```

`df1`: Currently new row is appended for every `5 Seconds`without validating the values which result in redundancy of the values.

```
    Curr_Time         Curr_Date
    11:43:34         10-04-2018
    11:43:34         10-04-2018
    11:45:34         10-04-2018
    11:45:34         10-04-2018
```

**Expected Output of `df1`**

```
    Curr_Time       Curr_Date  
    11:43:34        10-04-2018
    11:45:34        10-04-2018
```

Below is my R Code.

```
    library(tcltk2)

    df1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    df2 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

    frameupdate <- function(){
    if (nrow(df1)==0)
     df1 <<- df2
   else
     df1 <<- rbind(df1 , df2)
   }

      tclTaskSchedule(5000, frameupdate(), id = "frameupdate", redo = TRUE)
```

Comment: can you provide some example data and expected output? I am not sure if you mean `df1$Curr_Time==df2$Curr_Time` or `df1$Curr_Time %in% df2$Curr_Time`.

Comment: @SunLisa Sorry, its df1$Curr_Time == df2$Curr_Time. I will update the post with the example

Comment: after you updated with a reproducible example please let me know. I'd be glad to look at this question

Comment: use `dplyr::anti_join`

Comment: @SunLisa I have updated the post with the example.

Comment: `unique(df1)` will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @cephalopod mentioned, `anti_join` is a good way here.

You want to check that if the record in `df2` is already included in `df1` already.

You can do as @Stephan mentioned, after you append everything without checking if it's duplicated, run a `distinct()` to get distinct records

Or you can check every-time in your function, or use dplyr's `anti_join` function.

Here is the example for dplyr:

First I assume `df1` should not contain duplicated record (if logic was right from the very start)

```
df1<-df1 %>% unique()
head(df1)
  Curr_Time  Curr_Date
1  11:43:34 10-04-2018
3  11:45:34 10-04-2018
```

I created another record `df2.new` as an example for a new record that should be appended to `df1`:

```
df2.new
  Curr_Time  Curr_Date
1  11:45:57 10-04-2018
```

For example:

```
df2.new %>% anti_join(df1)
Joining, by = c("Curr_Time", "Curr_Date")
  Curr_Time  Curr_Date
1  11:45:57 10-04-2018

df2 %>% anti_join(df1)
Joining, by = c("Curr_Time", "Curr_Date")
[1] Curr_Time Curr_Date
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

It would work even if your `df1` was empty, therefore you can update your function like this:

```
frameupdate<-function(){
df1<<-rbind(df1, anti_join(df2,df1))
}
```

---

Or you could get something like this

```
frameupdate <- function(){
if (nrow(df1[df1$Curr_Time==df2$Curr_Time & df1$Curr_Date==df2$Curr_Date,])==0)
    df1 <<- rbind(df1 , df2)
  }

frameupdate()
```

Running this function would get the expected output, even when `df1` is empty.

```
df1
  Curr_Time  Curr_Date
1  11:43:34 10-04-2018
2  11:45:34 10-04-2018
3  11:45:57 10-04-2018
```

Answer (score 1):

After your `if else` statement you can follow with a simple validation:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  distinct()
```

which gives you:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Curr_Time Curr_Date 
   <time>    <chr>     
1 11:43     10-04-2018
2 11:45     10-04-2018
```